# C# EntityException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, entity

I have 76 checkboxes in my application. And I want to read some values from database when any of those checkboxes is checked. To read these values i create a backgroundworker every time a checkbox checked.

If i check these checkboxes one by one there is no problem. But if i check them all at once my database code throw an EntityException

```
    private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BackgroundWorker worker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
                worker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker1_DoWork);
                worker1.RunWorkerAsync(sender);

            }

void worker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)e.Argument).Checked == true)
            {
             ....Some Codes
                 var vv = (from value in d.tblValue join addres in d.tblAddres on value.AddresID equals addres.ID where value.AddresID == addresID && value.LoopDate >= startDate && value.LoopDate<= finishDate orderby value.LoopDate select new { value, addres }).ToList();
             ....Some Codes
             }
        }
```

Does It give this error becouse i put too much load to database?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the background workers? Having 76 separate background workers seems like a path that will only lead to deadlocks and tears. Also, what is the exception message?

Comment: What should i do instead of using 76 separate background workers?
Exception is The underlying provider failed to open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are re-using a previously created `DbContext` (variable `d`), which is not necessarily thread-safe. Try creating a new `DbContext` within the `worker1_DoWork` method (don't re-use a single instance).

```
void worker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (((CheckBox)e.Argument).Checked == true)
    {
     ....Some Codes

         using(var db = new MyFooEntities())
         {
             var vv = (from value in db.tblValue 
                       join addres in db.tblAddres on value.AddresID equals addres.ID 
                       where value.AddresID == addresID && 
                             value.LoopDate >= startDate && 
                             value.LoopDate<= finishDate 
                       orderby value.LoopDate 
                       select new { value, addres }).ToList();
         }

     ....Some Codes
     }
}
```